# How to group specific variables together in R

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, group-by

I have global data categorized into continents (Europe, Asia, Africa, N America, S America and Australia). I want to group into ecoregions (i.e. Eurasia+Africa, Americas and Australia). I am trying to use dplyr for this data but I fail to succeed.

`data <- data.frame(temp = c(1,2,3,4,5),region = c("Europe","Asia","N America", "S America","Australia")`

```
    temp    region
    1    1    Europe
    2    2      Asia
    3    3 N America
    4    4 S America
    5    5 Australia
```

I would ideally like to obtain something as such.

```
    temp    region    region_2
    1    1    Europe  Eurasia+Af
    2    2      Asia  Eurasia+Af
    3    3 N America  Americas
    4    4 S America  Americas
    5    5 Australia  Australia
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You want to use ``case_when`` from ``dplyr``.

Answer (score 0):

To build on the comment from user438383

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(temp = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                   region = c("Europe","Asia","N America", "S America","Australia"))


updatedDf <- data %>%
mutate(region_2 = case_when(
  region == 'N America'| region == 'S America' ~ "Americas", 
  region == 'Asia' | region == 'Africa' | region == 'Europe' ~ 'Eurasia+Africa', 
  region == 'Australia' ~ 'Australia', 
  TRUE ~ region)
  )
```

You can also use a str_detect function to clean up the code for Americas and eliminate the Australia line of code, because the TRUE ~ region line will handle instances when the region and region_2 are the same